# Mandatory profile giving corrupted recycle bin error for all users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-registry

I had to make a few changes to our mandatory profile and ever since that happened any user who logs in using the mandatory profile receives an error saying the \recyclebin\$specificUser$ is corrupted. Clearing the error doesn't help. The next time the user logs in they receive the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this, exactly? It's always the same user in the error.

Comment: What permissions are applied to the users Documents folder?

Comment: Authenticated users and Administrators have full control at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a permission issue.

Reapply the correct permission to the profile, including changing the owner and the error will go away

Comment: I've changed permissions to authenticated users. I've also changed the owner to administrators but I'm still receiving the same error.